# Wiring C wire in at a older unit

Tags: electrical, thermostat, wifi

e3eb-012h is the model number for a wiring diagram...

Trying to add a WiFi thermostat to my house, there is a blue wire ran but like most other topics on here it is not currently connected at the unit side of the wire... Feel like I should tie into one of the grey wires coming off the transformer but not completely sure and not trying to burn up my ac...

Appreciate the help!

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring diagram, as well as the make of the furnace please?

Comment: Is that the model number of the furnace, the thermostat, your car, what? Including both the brand and model numbers of all devices is most helpful.

Comment: Interesting: Instruction 6 says "not to exceed 120V" but the schematic calls for 240V on the transformer!

Answer (score 1):

An actual picture of the control board would help, but according to a [wiring diagram](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/669518/Nordyne-Air-Conditioner-Heat-Pump-Air-Handler.html?page=22#manual) that I can find any grey wire is the 0v reference from the 24v transformer.